# django url pattern matching to display different pages

Tags: django, django-views, django-urls

I'm new to django and I'm kinda confused on how to use django's url pattern matching.

This is my intention. I have 4 pages to a website. Depending on the links, they would use the url to find what information to present to the user. Also the url knows which page the user is on.

So the person would choose a building based on links.
The person would then choose the floor they wish to go on.
Finally the person would then choose a room.

> Ex. format: aaa.com/buildingname/floornumber/roomnumber
>
> step0   aaa.com/
>
> step1   aaa.com/django/
>
> step2   aaa.com/django/2/
>
> step3   aaa.com/django/2/201

So based on the url pattern, the website should load up differently every time.

Is this how I am supposed to use url pattern matching? I really would like to get some help on this. What should the url pattern look like? As of right now all I can think of is just matching the url into different apps that have views. I just don't know how to link them all together.

And I have a MySQL database with the building,floor,and room number.

Thanks in advance everybody. I appreciate your effort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define url pattern pointing to different views as follows:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('your_app.views', 
                   (r'^/(?P<building_name>\w+)/$','function1'),
                   (r'^/(?P<building_name>\w+)/(?P<floor>\d+)/$','function2'),
                   (r'^/(?P<building_name>\w+)/(?P<floor>\d+)/(?P<room>\d+)/$','function3'),
                   )
```

Use this pattern and it will call different views and in each view you can use different template. Or if you want to use same view function check for available values in URL and render whichever template you need. You can get the URL value in views as follows:

```
def function1(request, building_name = None):
    print building_name
```

Likewise do it for other views also.

Answer (score 1):

If you want them to be handled in the same view , you can pass arguments to the same view,

```
r('/(?P<building>\w+)/','views.view1')
r('/(?P<building>\w+)/(?P<flat>\w+)/','views.view1')
r('/(?P<building>\w+)/(?P<flat>\w+)/(?P<room>\w+)/','views.view1')
```

your view,

```
def view1(buidling="",flat="",room=""):
 return []
```

Comment: thanks. this worked great! now my other concern now is. should it really be one view or should there be multiple apps with different views? or should there be one app that can serve different views?

ex myapp
     -app
        -views
            -buildingview
            -flatview
            -roomview

or

-project
    -building_app
        -views
    -flat_app
        -views
    -room_app
        -views

Comment: @user805981 that depends on your application. I you are going to do almost similar tasks  despite the arguments, go for a single app with single view, and it becomes generic too.